# OOP - Visual Objects: Does VO support Interfaces like C#/Java Interface (for strategy design pattern)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, xbase, clipper

I'm a C#/Java developer and here on my new job we have a legacy system developed with Visual Objects (VO, from Computer Associates -- rough mode: VO = OO-Clipper), and I need to fix some modules and implement some patterns here (i.e.: strategy pattern) (VO is a object oriented language). However, I have VO 2.5 reference manual and I couldn't find any reference to "interface classes" like we have on C# and Java:

```
interface ISampleInterface
```

VO reference manual says that it supports polymorphism and inheritance, but no mention to interface, generics or else.

I know that this language is quite old but this legacy system still stands in production and have several clients that use this on a daily basis. A new version is being developed in C#, but we need to keep the legacy one alive.

Does anyone know if VO supports interfaces or, if not, how to develop something  like that (interfaces and the classes that implements these interfaces)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create DLL with set of functionality and use that Is'nt it?

Comment: @abdulrahmank Do you mean that I could do all my strategies in C#, encapsulating on a DLL/OCX/ActiveX or else and import that on VO?

Comment: Yeah kind of can it be done? Is it feasible to vreate dll in VO itself?